# About the life cycle of an android component

Tags: android, service, android-activity, lifecycle

First of all, I'm new in android developing...
I had read some article in android API guide and feel confused about the component life cycle with the hosting process.

Here is my understanding:

1. Android system may kill some activities in a process **or** the whole process in low memory situations,which means there is a possibility that a started activity may die, but process still alive.
2. If a service is started and not call any stop method, when in extreme low memory, this service is killed by system **with its hosting process**, not just the service itself, means this circumstance should not occur:service is killed by system, but hosting process still alive.
3. When an app starts, the user navigates activity1 -> activity2 -> activity3 and none of them call finish(). Next, the user navigates to another app's activity and plays with it so long that the former app process is killed by the system. Now the user navigate back to activity3 in the back-tracking stack, what will happens? The former app process restarts with **only** activity3 recreate?

Anything wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to switch to another app's activity: from the moment that you leave the first activity to go to the second activity; there is a clear possibility that the first activity might have been destroyed when you return on it from the second activity (back-tracking) and when you go to a third one, either the first one, the second or both of them can be possibly destroyed in the mean time.  In fact, you don't even to leave an activity to see it destroyed; as this will automatically happen simply if you switch from the portrait mode to the landscape mode and vice-versa by rotating the device.

When you return to an activity, the onRestart() function will be called if the activity has not been destroyed in the mean time.  If it has, the "onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" will be called instead but with the argument "savedInstanceState" set to a non-null value (ie, it will point toward a valid Bundle object) if you have took the precaution of saving the current state of the activity in the "onSaveInstanteState(Bundle outState)" function when the activity has entered the process of being destroyed by the system.  The system will always call this function before destroying an activity when this one need to be restored later for back-tracking.  Of course, it won't be called after a call to finish() because this will also remove the activity from the back-tracking stack.

Finally, in Android, the coupling between activities in the same application is very loose.  When it comes to the use of resources, there is not much of a difference between switching to an activity from the same application or from another application.  In many ways, activities will behave like if there were all fully independant applications when it comes to running.  This is why you always need to use an intent to start an activity; even when it is from the same application.

Comment: So i should consider every activity as a single 'app' and don't make any dependences between each other in the starting oder?(i.e activity2 may start without activity1 runs first)

Comment: Well, it all depends on the functionality presented by each activity.  For example, for a searching module, it will not be uncommon to have something like Activity1->Activity2->Activity3->Activity2->Activity3...; where the second instances of Activity2 and 3 not being an exact replica of their first instances.  At the end, it all depends on the needed functionality and the navigation options presented to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding ...

1. In android during low memory situations, first activities would be removed from memory where the onDestroy method gets called.
2. This is not the case always. It depends on how the service is started i.e whether from onStart or through Binding the service with a component.
3. Once the former app process is killed, then when the user launches the application, he will be taken to activity 1. Launching the activity in same task or different task depends on launch modes used (single task, etc)